# EXCEPTION: response.findIndex is not a function

Tags: javascript

From the api response, I want get index `results` array without using forEach. I found ES2016 solution below but When I run the following JavaScript I get

> EXCEPTION: response.findIndex is not a function

**JavaScript**

```
console.log( response.findIndex(x => x.results.id === 5 ) );
```

**Response**

```
{
"count": 9,
"results": [
    {
        "id": 8,
        "name": "Example 1"
    },
    {
        "id": 9,
        "name": "Example 2"
    }
    ....
]}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`findIndex` requires array but your response is an object. But property named `results` is an array.

Convert this

```
response.findIndex(x => x.results.id === 5 )
```

to this

```
response.results.findIndex(x => x.id === 5 )
```

Comment: It should be `response.results.findIndex(x => x.id == 5 )`

Comment: @NavneilNaicker Thanks for pointing out. You have a hawk eye mate :)